# mysql sum of product rows where data stamp within cost data range

Tags: mysql

I have three tables `product`, `cost` and `account`

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `datestamp` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `cost` (
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount` float NOT NULL,
  `datestamp` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=103 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

+-----+----------+-----------------+
| id  | name     | email           |
+-----+----------+-----------------+
| 101 | Acme Inc | jondoe@host.com |
+-----+----------+-----------------+

+------------+--------+------------+
| account_id | amount | datestamp  |
+------------+--------+------------+
|        101 |      5 | 2014-01-01 |
|        101 |     10 | 2014-01-03 |
|        101 |     15 | 2014-01-06 |
+------------+--------+------------+

+----+------------+---------+------------+
| id | account_id | name    | datestamp  |
+----+------------+---------+------------+
|  1 |        101 | Alfa    | 2014-01-01 |
|  2 |        101 | Bravo   | 2014-01-02 |
|  3 |        101 | Charlie | 2014-01-03 |
|  4 |        101 | Delta   | 2014-01-04 |
|  5 |        101 | Echo    | 2014-01-06 |
|  6 |        101 | Foxtrot | 2014-01-08 |
+----+------------+---------+------------+
```

I'd like to return the per unit cost and total quantity for each
account by matching the product row to it's cost based on the date stamps
and grouping those by cost and account so I can sum them.

Here is as far as I have got with the query but I'm stuck at trying
to match the product to the right price.

```
select
    a.id as account_id,
    count(p.id) as qty,
    c.amount as cost_per_unit,
    c.datestamp as cost_date,
    p.datestamp as product_date
from product p
left join account a on a.id = p.account_id
left join cost c on 1
where p.datestamp <is within right range based on cost date stamps>
group by c.amount, a.id
;
```

So if the amount was $5 on 2014-01-01 and $10 on 2014-01-3 and $15
on 2014-01-06 each product date stamped before the $10 date 
would be $5 and before the $15 would be $10 and so on..

Any suggestions on how to approach this one?

-- edit
Based on the answer below I was able to get what I needed with

```
SELECT 
    a.id AS account_id,
    COUNT(p.id) AS qty,
    c1.amount AS cost_per_unit,
    c1.datestamp AS cost_date
FROM cost c1
    INNER JOIN account a ON a.id = c1.account_id
    LEFT JOIN cost c2 ON c2.datestamp = 
    (
        select datestamp 
        from cost 
        where account_id = a.id 
        and datestamp > c1.datestamp 
        order by datestamp ASC 
        LIMIT 1
    )
    LEFT JOIN product p ON p.datestamp >= c1.datestamp
WHERE p.datestamp < c2.datestamp OR c2.datestamp IS NULL
GROUP BY a.id, c1.amount
ORDER BY c1.datestamp ASC
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely to be brutally inefficient in a production environment, but for your tinkering enjoyment this query should get you most of the way there. I know you're able to polish off the edges as you're doing great so far :)

```
SELECT a.id AS account_id,
    COUNT(p.id) AS qty,
    c2.amount AS previous_cost_per_unit,
    c1.amount AS cost_per_unit,
    c1.datestamp AS cost_date,
    p.datestamp AS product_date
FROM product p
    INNER JOIN account a ON a.id = p.account_id
    INNER JOIN cost c1 ON c1.account_id = p.account_id AND c1.datestamp = p.datestamp
    LEFT JOIN cost c2 ON c2.datestamp = (SELECT MAX(datestamp) FROM cost WHERE account_id = c1.account_id AND datestamp < c1.datestamp)
GROUP BY account_id, product_date
```